# How to show bytes of float

Tags: c

I personally use a function show_bytes as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef char *byte_pointer;

void show_bytes (byte_pointer x)
{
        int length = sizeof(float);
        int i;
        for(i = 0;i <length;i++)
        {
                printf("%2x",*(x+i));
                printf("\n");
        }
}

int main()
{
        float obj;
        printf("please input the value of obj:");
        scanf("%f",&obj);
        show_bytes((byte_pointer) &obj);
}
```

when i input 120.45,which should be 0x42f0e666

```
please input the value of obj:120.45
66
ffffffe6
fffffff0
42
```

why so many 'f' before the e6 and f0 while i use %.2x.

Comment: It seems that for your compiler `char` is *signed*. Now think about how that information applies to a case where you want to print *unsigned* data.

Comment: If you need "bytes" (i.e. not "characters") don't use `char`. use `uint8_t` instead.

Comment: Yes,I replace char with unsigned char, it turns out to be the answer i want..Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Your function should be:

```
void show_bytes (byte_pointer x)
{
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i <sizeof(float); i++)
   {
      printf("0x%2X\n", (unsigned int)(*(x++) & 0xFF));
   }
}
```

or

```
typedef uint8_t *byte_pointer;

void show_bytes (byte_pointer x)
{
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i <sizeof(float); i++)
   {
      printf("0x%2X\n", *(x++));
   }
}
```

In your code the problem is that the pointer type is `signed` an is promoted to `signed int` by `printf`.

`%2X` format does not limit the output digit, tells only to printf that the result string must be **at least** 2 characters long.

- First solution: the value is promoted to `signed int` but the passed
  value is truncated to the LSB.
- Second example: value is truncated by the type of pointer, that
  is `unsigned char`.

**The rule is:** *to raw access memory, always use unsigned types.*